# How to read Google Play crash report

Tags: android, crash

I'm new in android world. I have built a tiny App and published  it  in Google Play Store. I just noticed that there is a  crash report from three devices. I tried to read it but I couldn't tell which part of the App is crashing. Also, I didn't find an article about how to read this report.

This is one of the reports:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at android.widget.ListView.setupChild (ListView.java:1854)
  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView (ListView.java:1816)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown (ListView.java:697)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop (ListView.java:763)
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1627)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout (AbsListView.java:2166)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout (ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout (ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1671)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1525)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1434)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15033)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:4799)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2151)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1862)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:5993)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:574)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:544)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:747)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5584)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

I will be grateful if anybody can show me how to trace this back the App

Comment: Typically there will be the stack trace with a specific item highlighted that actually caused the error. Maybe it isn't the case with this though

Comment: Yes, I thinks so. Because I did just what @Mohammad Ersan said, and it didn't refer to any of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the crash (ctrl+v) then from the Android Studio "Analyze" menu select "Analyze Stacktrace" option:

[image: Analyze Stacktrace Option]

after that, you can paste your copied log/stacktrace and click over "OK" and then Android Studio will highlight in blue which part of the stacktrace is in your code.

[image: Stacktrace higlight]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But it didn't refer to any of my code